# Why is onKeyDown not working in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm trying to build a sudoku app with React and I've separated everything into 4 components. It basically goes like this App -> Board -> Row -> Cell where the cell is the smallest unit. Now every cell is a `<div>` tag for which I used `tabIndex="0"` to navigate with the keys and enter values in the cell.

I render all my cells by using `.map()` to go through an array of data. Initially, I didn't specify a `key` property for every element of my array and everything was working fine. Every cell I had was working perfectly whenever I pressed a key. However, as soon as I specify a `key` property of the cell it seems like my handler function for `onKeyDown` isn't working at all. I'm completely baffled, if anyone has any insights I would appreciate it.

Just to specify, I'm using `uuid()` to generate a unique key but every other method I've tried doesn't work as well. It seems to be some relationship between the `key` property and the `onKeyDown` event.

This is what I return as a cell: `<div id={props.id} tabIndex="0" className={className} onKeyDown={(e)=> {handleKeyDown(e)}}> {value} </div>`

And this is how I map through a row to render cells: `const cells = rowContent.map((cell, cellIndex) => { return <Cell key={uuid()} solution={props.solution} activeSquare={props.activeSquare} value={cell === "." ? null : cell} id={startNum+cellIndex+1} selected={selected} /> })`

Comment: Which element is the `onKeyDown` event on? How have you declared it? Seeing some code would be more useful than a description of the code.

Comment: You also definitely shouldn't be using `uuid()` for `key`, it's equal or worse than not specifying a key.

Comment: I edited my question, sorry, it's my first time asking a question in here. Do you know a better way to generate a unique key for each cell?

Comment: The row index is enough for each row, and the cell index is enough for each cell. The keys don't need to be unique across the universe, just in the context they're rendered in.